GIGABYTE B450M DS3H w/ Ryzen 5 3600 PCIe bifurcation
I have the GIGABYTE B450M DS3H with a Ryzen 5 3600 processor and want to install an Asus Hyper 4x M.2 expansion card.
Before buying the expansion card I went to Google and found the manual of my motherboard (page 16) which clearly states that PCIe bifurcation is supported, however, now that I've installed the card that option seems to not be present and I don't know why.

There is a note at the bottom:

(Note) This item is present only when you install a CPU that supports
this feature.

Although for non-G CPU's it should work. There was extensive table from ASUS, which showed that 3000-series CPUs do support bifurcation on 16x slot connected to CPU. Link for reference, showing that it is possible in this chipset and CPU.
You need to make sure you are installing the card into upper PCI-e 16x slot (typically used for graphics cards).
You can use search in UEFI ("BIOS") settings to see if bifurcation or PCI-e configuration options are buried somewhere. Also, if not done already, try to update to the latest version of UEFI.
If you wanted to have bifurcation on a non-CPU PCI-e slot you're out of luck. It won't work on any AM4/AM5 platforms, only on server ones with many more PCI-e lines.
